# How do i change dynamically textview in one single row only

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

As you can see in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIlTG.png) image, my coordinate is changing dynamically by `\n`. I want it to show only last coordinates in one row only, just changing dynamically, how do i do that?

This is my code:

```
tv_loc.append("Lattitude: " + lattitude + "  Longitude: " + longitude + "\n");
```

Comment: i try setting in android:maxLines="1" , it stuck only in first coordinate

Comment: if you only want one row, then change `tv_loc.append()` to `tv_loc.setText()`

Comment: @Sagar yes it works, thank

Comment: Great! I have added it as answer, help me to approve, so that others can get benefit too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `append()` then every time you call it, it will append a new line. Since your intention is to update same row, then use following

`tv_loc.setText("Lattitude: " + lattitude + "  Longitude: " + longitude + "\n");`

**Instead of**

`tv_loc.append("Lattitude: " + lattitude + "  Longitude: " + longitude + "\n");`

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the text and not append it.

When you append a text it will add to the end of the String. Lets say that you have this code:

```
String tv_loc = "";

For(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    tv_loc.append(i + " ");
}

system.out.println(tv_loc);
```

It will print `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`, because you are **appending** it.

To solve this you need to **update** the text, to do this you can use the `setText()` function (assuming that `tv_loc` is a TextView object), like

`tv_loc.setText("Lattitude: " + lattitude + "  Longitude: " + longitude);`

(The `\n` is not necessary)